Does performing row echelon form of a submatrix preserve the matrix rank?
Let's say you transform a square matrix $A$ into one of its row echelon form, $\hat{A}$, so that $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(\hat{A})$. You can divide $\hat{A}$ into four sub-matrices:
$$\hat{A} = \begin{bmatrix}B & C \\ 0 & D\end{bmatrix}$$
where $B$ and $D$ are generally upper-triangular marices, and $C$ is the upper-right section of $\hat{A}$.
If you turn $C$ into one of its its row echelon form $\hat{C}$, is it true that
$$\text{rank}(\begin{bmatrix}B & \hat{C} \\ 0 & D\end{bmatrix}) = \text{rank}(\begin{bmatrix}B & C \\ 0 & D\end{bmatrix})$$
?
If yes, does this apply more generally, i.e. for any sub-matrix of any square matrix $A$? How about for non-square matrices?
Does anything change if we use reduced row echelon form (rref) instead of just row echelon form?

For general case no. Consider the following
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc|cc}a&b&1&0 \\0&0&2&0 \end{array} \right)\quad\mbox{and}\quad \left( \begin{array}{cc|cc}a&b&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \end{array} \right). $$
The right hand matrix has right block replaced with its echelon form and the rank is $1$. The left hand matrix is of rank $2$ if either $b\neq 0$ or $a\neq 0$.

Thank you -- if you let $D=0$, I think this directly answers my original question too

@user3667125 indeed, we can add two blocks of zeroes at the bottom
